# I got an error on my project after updating flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I have explicitly added firebase_core_platform_interface to pubspec.yaml but still not working

this is the error message

```
: Error: Member not found: 'FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends'.
firebase_app.dart:18
    FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends(_delegate);
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
: Error: The method 'FallThroughError' isn't defined for the class 'ActionCodeInfo'.
action_code_info.dart:64
- 'ActionCodeInfo' is from 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/action_code_info.dart' ('../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_auth_platform_interface-4.3.1/lib/src/action_code_info.dart').
action_code_info.dart:1
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'FallThroughError'.
        throw FallThroughError();
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
: Error: Method not found: 'FallThroughError'.
load_bundle_task_state.dart:13
```

on its pubspec. lock

```
firebase_core_platform_interface:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description:
      name: firebase_core_platform_interface
      sha256: b63e3be6c96ef5c33bdec1aab23c91eb00696f6452f0519401d640938c94cba2
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "4.8.0"
```

Help me to be able to run my previous project

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. delete pubspec.lock
2. do a flutter clean
3. Run flutter pub get (should return output 0)
4. Build the project again(in debug mode)